# Robokassa hash compaire incorrect

Tags: php, hash, magento2

Problem with compare Robokassa confirm hash. Code bellow works fine, it's redirects to Robokassa.

```
$hashData = [
    "MrchLogin" => $this->login,
    "OutSum"    => round($sum, 2),
    "InvId"     => $invId,
    "pass"      => $this->password_1,
];
$hash = strtoupper(hash('md5', implode(":", $hashData)));
```

Everything works fine until i get back to my shop. Code bellow outputs "Incorrect Hash".

```
$hashData = [
    "OutSum" => round($sum, 2),
    "InvId"  => $invId,
    "pass"   => $this->password_2
];
$hash = strtoupper(hash('md5', implode(":", $hashData)));
$correctHash = (strcmp($hash, strtoupper($data['SignatureValue'])) == 0);
if (!$correctHash) {
    exit("Incorrect Hash");
}
```

Comment: And why there's no `MrchLogin` in second code?

Comment: I just modified magento 1 extension (https://bitbucket.org/etws/et_paymentrobokassa) as I didn't found how to do this operation in technical dock. I tried to add `MrchLogin` to second hash, still not same :(